# How to partially transit between 2 views, or 2 activities I'm not sure, in Android?

Tags: android, transition

As a non native English speaker, I'm not sure if I expressed the problem precisely, so I captured 2 screenshots to help you guys understand.
The pics are as follows: when I press the menu button in Pic1, which is at the top-right coner; there will play a transition animation to Pic2, but the view(or activity in Pic1) doesn't go out of the screen totally. And when I touch the Pic1 part, the pic1 will come back to the screen.

I wonder how to achieve this effect.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

[image: Pic1]

[image: Pic2]

Answer (score 0):

The native way to handle this is the Navigation drawer. You will find demosources at Android developers page: https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html